# Query Change from MySQL to MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

i have a view in MySQL but for some reason i want it to write in MS Access..i have already imported neccessary tables. when i copy the view definaation from MySQL and write it in Access Query Design it gives me error on "Join operation".What's wrong here ?

View -> qryOccupation

```
    select `a`.`Employee_ID` AS `Employee_ID`,`a`.`Employee_Name` AS `Employee_Name`,`a`.`Flat_No` AS `Flat_No`,`a`.`Area` AS `Area`,`a`.`Building_Name` AS `Building_Name` 
from (`tblallotment` `a` join `tblflat` `f`) 
where ((`a`.`Flat_No` = `f`.`Flat_No`) 
and (`f`.`Status` = 'A') 
and (not(`a`.`Employee_ID` in 
(select `c`.`Employee_ID` 
from (`tblallotment` `a` join `tblcancel_allotment` `c`) 
where ((`a`.`Employee_ID` = `c`.`Employee_ID`) 
and (`c`.`Date_Cancellation` = 0))))))
```

Comment: You need to mention what the JOIN is ON ... take a look at this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Can u show me one example by modifying above query ?

Comment: I have posted the example below.Mention always the column you are performing the join on and mayb in you case...I am not sure about ur requirement but should be like: from (`tblallotment` `a` join `tblflat` `f`)  on ((`a`.`Flat_No` = `f`.`Flat_No`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.Employee_ID AS Employee_ID,
       a.Employee_Name AS Employee_Name,
       a.Flat_No AS Flat_No,
       a.Area AS Area,
       a.Building_Name AS Building_Name 
from   tblallotment a 
          inner join tblflat f 
            on a.Flat_No = f.Flat_No 
where  f.Status = 'A'
       and (not (a.Employee_ID in 
                (select c.Employee_ID 
                 from   tblallotment a 
                         inner join tblcancel_allotment c 
                            on a.Employee_ID = c.Employee_ID
                  where c.Date_Cancellation = 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
("SELECT [Department Name], " _
        & "FirstName & Chr(32) & LastName AS Name " _
        & "FROM Departments LEFT JOIN Employees " _
        & "ON Departments.[Department ID] = " _
        & "Employees.[Department ID] " _
        & "ORDER BY [Department Name];")
```